# .htaccess rewrite override the menu button

Tags: html, css, .htaccess, menu, styling

Redirect index.html to Home Page to Root to get `https://www.example.com/` (obsolet ".html"):

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^index.html$ / [R=301,L] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)/index.html$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

SEO-friendly URLs `https://example.com/cool-page.html` to `https://example.com/cool-page`:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

Above .htaccess conditions *override* the menu tab effects.

Before implementing the above rules my menu button was *highlighted* when visiting any of my webpages:
[Example with highlighting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hlK4O.png)

When I apply the rules the button is not *highlighted*:
[Example without highlighting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hzyeT.png)

Anyone has any suggestions to get the menu button highlighted again while using the above rewrite rules?

Comment: I reformatted your question so that it is readable: I removed all the bold and uppercase stuff, formatted the code, formatted the links and gave a meaningful title to the image references. Hope you don't mind that. But if no one can read your question you won't get an answer ...

Comment: As it stands there is not enough information in the question to give an answer. The rewriting rules themselves are not directly responsible for the effect you describe. There has to be something else: either some logic on the server side (not very likely in static html pages). Or, more likely, some client side logic (javascript) that evaluates the actual URL that is requested by the browser to decide whether that button should get highlighted or not. You'd need to add that part of your javascript logic to the question for us to be able to help with that.

Comment: What URL are you linking to in your HTML source? For instance, for the HOME button you should be linking to `href=“/“`, not `href=“/index.html”`. If you link to the later then your link will not be highlighted, since these requests are being redirected.